# Non-binomial posteriors for a binomial prior?

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, prior, posterior, beta-distribution

Let's assume we have a discrete binary random variable K (K=0 or K=1) for which the prior distribution is binomial. My understanding of Bayesian statistics tells me that regardless of the likelihood, the posterior distribution for K can only be binomial as well. However, I have encountered a text which talks about "beta posterior for a binomial prior" -- am I correct that this is wrong?

Comment: Can you give more of the text?  It probably means a Beta (hyper)prior for the binomial prior.  And that Beta prior can be updated, so it has a prior value, a likelihood and a posterior.

Comment: What is your observational data? You have prior distribution of $k\sim B(n,p)$. What is your observational data? And what is your conditional distribution? If your observational data is $k$, then it becomes the maximum likelihood estimation, with nothing to do with the posterior. $p(k|X)\propto p(k)L(k|X)$. What is your observational data $X$? If your observational data is your successful rate $p$, first of all, how do you get your observation of $p$? If it is, then what is $L(k|X)$? If $L(k|X)=\Pi f(X)$, then we have $p(k|X)=p(k)$, a binomial distribution.

Comment: @NeilG No, the text doesn't discuss hyperpriors.

Comment: @quant_dev: They may not have used that term, but a Beta distribution is the conjugate prior for the Bernoulli distribution, which is the most likely explanation.  Why don't you give more of the text?

Comment: I cannot post the original text, buy it says about using multinomial logistic regression for modelling measured data.

Comment: @quant_dev: Then it sounds like rather than updating the parameters by, for example, gradient descent, the learning algorithm is updating a prior on the parameters, which is beta-distributed (or Dirichlet in general).

Answer (score 1):

1) Let $K\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$. When you observe a random sample, you get $n$ realizations of $K$ and try to guess $p$.
So your random sample is a realization of the multiple random variable $(K_1,\dots,K_n)$.
$Y=\sum_{i=1}^n K_i$ is equal to the number of $K_i=1$, is the number of "successes" in your sample and $y/n$ ($y$ is the realization of $Y$) is your best guess about $p$. For example, if you get 100110101110, where $y=7$ and $n=12$, $p$ is *likely* close to $7/12$. So the binomial distribution of $Y$, $Y\sim\text{B}(n,p)$, is your *likelihood*, not your prior!
You need a likelihood, not a prior, for $K$ -- better: for $y$. Then you need a prior for $p$ ($n$ is known).

2) The posterior *always* depends on both prior and likelihood, because is just their product. So you can never say that is something "regardless of the likelihood". Moreover, you are looking for a posterior for $p$ (the unknown parameter in $K\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$) conditional to the realizations of $K$, not a posterior for $K$.

3) If you assume that the prior for $p$ is $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, then your posterior will be $\text{Beta}(y+\alpha,n-y+\beta)$, as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Beta-binomial_distribution_as_a_compound_distribution). This is called "coniugacy" -- when prior and posterior belong to the same family -- and is computationally convenient; so this is why a beta prior is often used when the *likelihood* is binomial.